# How to validate two sets of radio buttons in one form using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, radio-button

I have two sets of radio buttons in one form. You're not supposed to be able to send the form if you haven't checked one radio button per set. If possible, I would like a solution with **JS only** (no jQuery). I found a helpful function in an older question on here and tried to adapt it to my case, but I obviously failed. Where's my mistake?

```
<form>

<input type="radio" name="date_1" id="dat-1_27-10" value="2017-10-27" <?php echo $checked1 ;?> />
<input type="radio" name="date_1" id="dat-1_28-10" value="2017-10-28" <?php echo $checked2 ;?> />
<input type="radio" name="date_1" id="dat-1_03-11" value="2017-11-03" <?php echo $checked3 ;?> />
<input type="radio" name="date_1" id="dat-1_04-11" value="2017-11-04" <?php echo $checked4 ;?> />

<input type="radio" name="date_2" id="dat-2_27-10" value="2017-10-27" <?php echo $checked5 ;?> />
<input type="radio" name="date_2" id="dat-2_28-10" value="2017-10-28" <?php echo $checked6 ;?> />
<input type="radio" name="date_2" id="dat-2_03-11" value="2017-11-03" <?php echo $checked7 ;?> />
<input type="radio" name="date_2" id="dat-2_04-11" value="2017-11-04" <?php echo $checked8 ;?> />

<input type="submit" name="send" value="send" id="submit" onclick='return validateDateOne(); return validateDateTwo();'/>

</form>

<script>

function validateDateOne() {
      if (!$("input[name='date_1']:checked").val()) {
          alert('Please choose your favourite date');
          return false;
      }
      else {}
}

function validateDateTwo() {
      if (!$("input[name='date_2']:checked").val()) {
           alert('Please choose a second date');
           return false;
      }
      else {}
}

</script>
```

Comment: Have one function to validate. In that function add your logic

Comment: Just trying to validate _one_ of the sets of radio buttons by completely deleting the function _validateDateTwo()_ doesnt't work, though. There must be an error in the function itself, I suppose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group your checks together in one function. Also I would recommend to attach a submit handler with jQuery.

Here is a working [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/j520ywkq/)

```
<input type="submit" name="send" value="send" id="submit" />


$('#myform').submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
      if (!$("input[name='date_1']:checked").val()) {
          alert('Please choose your favourite date');
          return;
      }
        if (!$("input[name='date_2']:checked").val()) {
           alert('Please choose a second date');
           return;
      }
      alert("submit")
});
```

Note that the Jquery submit handler is wrapped in a onDomReady Handler.

Also: Client Side Validation is **NEVER** safe. To be sure with the input data, validate it on the backend, too.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the security issues! In this case, though, I'm asked to write a client side only realisation as a project to learn JS.

Comment: @lioness that's totally fine, but keep it in mind ;) 
This solution works on client side, though.

Comment: As for your code, I only changed the ID "#myform" after copying it but it doesn't seem to work? Instead, my other function to check if all regular text fields are filled in now doesn't work anymore, either.

Comment: Have you wrapped the javascript code by a document ready handler?
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: The document ready handler made my other functions work again indeed, but I still can't make your code work. I'm sorry, I'm really a complete beginner, and although I've gotten to know some basic JS during the last days, I've never used jQuery before (I did embed jQuery, though... Correctly, I hope). Is there a JS only solution by any chance?

Comment: I recommend to read this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms/Form_validation

Comment: Turns out the problem was the embedding of jQuery all along! Thank you for your time and effort, I finally made it work!

Comment: Great! Glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Call the function `validateDateTwo()` with retrun statement inside the else condition of function `validateDateOne()` instead of calling it in onclick.

For **Pure JS** solution,i used `querySelector` instead of `$`.

```js
function validateDateOne() {
      if (!document.body.querySelector("input[name='date_1']:checked")) {
          alert('Please choose your favourite date');
          return false;
      }
      else {
         return validateDateTwo();
      }
}

function validateDateTwo() {
      if (!document.body.querySelector("input[name='date_2']:checked")) {
           alert('Please choose a second date');
           return false;
      }
      else {}
}
```

```html
<form>

<input type="radio" name="date_1" id="dat-1_27-10" value="2017-10-27"  />2017-10-27
<input type="radio" name="date_1" id="dat-1_28-10" value="2017-10-28"  />2017-10-28
<input type="radio" name="date_1" id="dat-1_03-11" value="2017-10-28"  />2017-10-28
<input type="radio" name="date_1" id="dat-1_04-11" value="2017-11-04"  />2017-11-04
<br/>
<input type="radio" name="date_2" id="dat-2_27-10" value="2017-10-27"  />2017-10-27
<input type="radio" name="date_2" id="dat-2_28-10" value="2017-10-28"  />2017-10-28
<input type="radio" name="date_2" id="dat-2_03-11" value="2017-11-03"  />2017-10-28
<input type="radio" name="date_2" id="dat-2_04-11" value="2017-11-04"  />2017-11-04

<input type="submit" name="send" value="send" id="submit" onclick='return validateDateOne();'/>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with  validate the `checked` box length and add the `validation` function in `onsubmit` of the form instead of `button` click .no need a two function only single function is enough

```js
function validateDate() {
  if (!$("input[name='date_1']:checked").length) //validate first one
  {
    console.log('select any one in first part');
    return false;
  }
  if (!$("input[name='date_2']:checked").length) //validate second one
  {
    console.log('select any one in second part')
    return false;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form onsubmit="return validateDate()">
  <!--only do with single function-->

  <input type="radio" name="date_1" id="dat-1_27-10" value="2017-10-27" <?php echo $checked1 ;?> />
  <input type="radio" name="date_1" id="dat-1_28-10" value="2017-10-28" <?php echo $checked2 ;?> />
  <input type="radio" name="date_1" id="dat-1_03-11" value="2017-11-03" <?php echo $checked3 ;?> />
  <input type="radio" name="date_1" id="dat-1_04-11" value="2017-11-04" <?php echo $checked4 ;?> />

  <input type="radio" name="date_2" id="dat-2_27-10" value="2017-10-27" <?php echo $checked5 ;?> />
  <input type="radio" name="date_2" id="dat-2_28-10" value="2017-10-28" <?php echo $checked6 ;?> />
  <input type="radio" name="date_2" id="dat-2_03-11" value="2017-11-03" <?php echo $checked7 ;?> />
  <input type="radio" name="date_2" id="dat-2_04-11" value="2017-11-04" <?php echo $checked8 ;?> />

  <input type="submit" name="send" value="send" id="submit" />

</form>
```